# How do I make a Windows Forms control respond to a DirectShow message?

Tags: .net, winforms, event-handling, directshow

I am constructing a simple video player with a playlist using Windows Forms.  The playlist is a ListBox control and I'm using the DirectShow.NET library to play the videos on a PictureBox control.

I need my playlist to respond (start playing the next video) once the video loaded in the picture box stops playing.  I understand that DirectShow sends the message EC_COMPLETE when the media is done.  (With the DS.NET library, this comes through as an enum simply called "EventCode.Complete")

How do I construct an event that triggers so that my playlist responds when that EC_COMPLETE message fires?  I've been re-reading over events, delegates, and event handling on MSDN, Stack Overflow and various other places online all day, but everything seems to be geared toward working with events already built into .NET.  For example, button clicks and all that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DirectShow.NET samples provide you with examples how `EC_COMPLETE` can be caught and handled.

For example, `PlayWnd` sample and `\Samples\Players\PlayWnd\MainForm.cs` file:

```
    private void HandleGraphEvent()
    {
// ...
      // Process all queued events
      while(this.mediaEventEx.GetEvent(out evCode, out evParam1, out evParam2, 0) == 0)
      {
// ...
        if(evCode == EventCode.Complete)
        {
```

The code is executed in response to the event of interest. The initialization includes providing (one of the methods) your window handle to the Filter Graph Manager (FGM), so that a window message is posted when event is available. Then C# code in the sample shows how to handle it through `WndProc` and deliver to the fragment quoted above.

This is how the whole event posting is enabled on the FGM:

```
  // Have the graph signal event via window callbacks for performance
  hr = this.mediaEventEx.SetNotifyWindow(this.Handle, WMGraphNotify, IntPtr.Zero);
```